# How to develop a Web Cam Service

Tags: web, streaming, webcam

I'm doing a project in which two people have to interact via a webcam on a website I am creating. Know some tool (language, code or program) that allows me (for free) to lift a web cam on this site?

So far I have knowledge of html, css, js, jquery and php (web part) but I think that none of these languages ​​is the most proper resources to access this type.

Can you help me? (Sorry for my bad English, not my native language)

Comment: you need a webcam tool that will help you to interact when creating a project, or you need to develop such a tool ?

Comment: Either. If it is a tool that allows me to configure it (and is free), and, if none exists, i would program it myself (which prefer not to), that language would have to do and where to start?